# User Logon setup on dapp with minimal ether

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design

For my project, I have to set up a user login option on the site (dapp) home page. I do not wish to have conventional server-side setup to save login details. Instead, I want to use web3 based Metamask or related options. 
For a simple log-on to the site, I do not wish to charge any ether from the user.

But the side-effect of this implementation will be on the mining of the transaction. Becuase of no incentive associated, I understand that mining of the transaction will be delayed as miners will not be interested because of zero incentives.

Is there any viable option which can trade-off both the aforementioned cases?

I believe many fellow developers must have come across this scenario, please suggest how to circumvent it. Will appreciate if supporting code or blog links can be provided that I can follow for further details?

Please excuse me for my noob status in smart contract design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authenticating user via smart contract doesn't sound like a good pattern at all for the reason you mentioned. Nobody is going to pay to login to a service.

However, Metamask stores a private/public key pair for you and provides with the web3 library a set of cryptographic functions. One of them is called [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography)

Using this method, you can implement a password-less authentication where:

- The enduser signs a [piece a data with web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign) and sends it to the server with his account address
- An authentication server can then recover the account address from signature and validate that the piece of data was signed by the user.
- The authentication server returns a JWT if the authentication is successful.

There is very good JavaScript tutorial available [here](https://hackernoon.com/never-use-passwords-again-with-ethereum-and-metamask-b61c7e409f0d)